# Sinon stub not called after promise returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to add more tests to my code with Mocha, Chai and Sinon, however I'm struggling to understand why this second stubbed function isn't recognised as being called.

I have a function that sends an email to a user (I'll test the email functionality later - for now I just want to get a handle on stubbing dependencies that I control)

```
// EmailSender.js
const models = require('../models');
const User = models.user;
const emailLogger = require('./emailLogger');

class EmailSender {
  constructor(subject, emailData) {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.emailData = emailData;
  }

  sendToUser() {
    let email = this.emailData.email;

    User.findOne({ where: { $or: [
      { email: email },
      { workEmail: email },
    ] } })
    .then(function (userData) {
      if (userData) {
        emailLogger.log('Send to anon - sending to user ' + userData.id);
      });
    } else {
      emailLogger.log('Send to anon - no user found');
    }
  }
}
```

And a test file:

```
const EmailSender = require('../../../helpers/emailSender');
const models = require('../../../models');
const User = models.user;
const emailLogger = require('../../../helpers/emailLogger');
const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");

const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('The emailSender', () => {
  let emailData;

  beforeEach(() => {
    emailData = {
      email: 'testemail@eml.co'
    };
    sinon.stub(User, 'findOne').returns(Promise.resolve());
    sinon.stub(emailLogger, 'log');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    User.findOne.restore();
    emailLogger.log.restore();
  })

  describe('sendToUser method', () => {
    it('logs an email if a user is found', () => {
      let emailSender = new EmailSender('Email subject', emailData);
      emailSender.sendToUser();

      expect(User.findOne).to.have.been.calledOnce; // works
      expect(emailLogger.log).to.have.been.calledOnce; // doesn't
    })
  })
});
```

I can stub the User.findOne() method with Sinon, but when I try and stub the emailLogger.log() method I get into trouble. It appears to call the stub and not the real method, but `expect(emailLogger.log).to.have.been.calledOnce` returns false.

I've tried adding `done()` and a fake timer in case there was a delay issue, as well as a range of other things, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

A great trick is to return the promise from the test function, which causes Mocha to wait until the promise completes. Here's how you'd do this:

```
it('logs an email if a user is found', () => {
   const emailSender = new EmailSender('Email subject', emailData);
   return emailSender.sendToUser().then( () => {  
      //check after the sendToUser promise is complete, but before the test is done  
      expect(User.findOne).to.have.been.calledOnce; 
      expect(emailLogger.log).to.have.been.calledOnce; 
   });
 });
```

This has the added benefit that if the promise fails for any reason, the test will fail to (with the correct error).

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever return the promise from the `sendToUser` function, which means there is no way of knowing when it actually completes. As you are testing an `async` function in a synchronous manner, that means you are asking if `emailLogger.log` has been called, *before* it is being called in the code!

You need to return the promise, and then you can do what Duncan proposes in his answer.